# When will KeepKey support Monero?

Tags: security, hardware-wallet

I asked this of keepkey about a year ago and I only have gotten a standard response saying they are evaluating the support of alts. Is anyone aware of progress made to support Monero?

Comment: I do not how this question is speculative. I voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was discussed in the [dev meeting](https://getmonero.org/2016/08/28/overview-and-logs-for-the-dev-meeting-held-on-2016-08-28.html) held on 2016-08-28:

> **fluffypony:** NoodleDoodle: do you want to talk about Trezor at all?
>
> **NoodleDoodle:** Sure :P
>
> **fluffypony:** yay, take it away
>
> **NoodleDoodle:** I'm about 1296 behind in commits. Rebasing is pretty much out of the question. Have to manually merge then release.
>
> **fluffypony:** NoodleDoodle: do you want any help with that?
>
> **NoodleDoodle:** The trezor firmware itself should be easier, except it's split into 5 or 6 repos
>
> **fluffypony:** ok cool
>
> **NoodleDoodle:** I should be able to do it.
>
> **fluffypony:** NoodleDoodle: do you want us to host it on the monero-project Github in its own repo, obvs giving you collab access, to make it more "formal" and part of the core project?
>
> **NoodleDoodle:** Sure, anything. I actually started on keepkey awhile back as well, although it's not as complete as trezor.
>
> **fluffypony:** ok cool
>
> **fluffypony:** I've been fiddling with Ledger Blue, as I have the Blue and the Nano S
>
> **fluffypony:** I have a feeling they'll be a cinch after Trezor / Keepkey
>
> **fluffypony:** and, hopefully, we can PR it in to be part of the default firmware on these devices
>
> **fluffypony:** if they'll have us

Comment: Unfortunately Trezor development has stopped and the code was removed from GitHub.  See more info [here on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TREZOR/comments/5ezhly/monero_with_trezor/) and in the [Monero Forum anouncment](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing).